# RISC-V ISA Input and Output operations

Tags: riscv

I didn't see anything in ISA 2.0 that talks about IO. Is RISC-V IO memory mapped ?   Are there any specification on how IO is suppose to be done ?
Do I get to define my own method ?    TIA.

Comment: This is off topic for SO

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is memory mapped. The exact specifications are still being worked out, as there are attempts to factor things as cleanly as possible to promote reuse. It was even the topic of long [conversation](https://lists.riscv.org/lists/arc/hw-dev/2015-07/msg00010.html) on the riscv-hw mailing list. Virtio is the direction things seem to be heading.

If you define your own now, you of course run the risk of needing to port things when it is standardized later on.